# Orthogonal complement $V^\bot$ of the vector space $V=\langle(1,0,2),(3,-1,0)\rangle$ and $V\cap V^\bot$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the inner product defined by polarizing the quadratic form $$q(x,y,z)=x^2-z^2+4xy-2yz$$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $V=\langle(1,0,2),(3,-1,0)\rangle$. Could you show me how to find $V^\bot$ and $V\cap V^\bot$? I get $V^\bot=\langle(2,6,1)\rangle$, which doesn't feel right, and don't know how to calculate the intersection. Also, in general, what can we say about the dimension of $W^\bot$ if we know the dimension of $W$?

Comment: One can produce a cross product $\times$ compatible with $q$ by regarding the volume form $\sqrt{3} \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ of $q$ as a map $V \times V \to V^*$ and composing this with the isomorphism $V^* \to V$ given by "raising an index" with respect to $q$. Then, $V^{\perp}$ is spanned by $(1, 0, 2) \times (3, -1, 0)$.

Comment: @Travis Could you show me some more standard reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric bilinear form that gives rise to your quadratic form $q$ is given by
$$
  b((x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2))=x_1x_2-z_1z_2+2x_1y_2+2y_1x_2-y_1z_2-z_1y_2
$$
Now the conditions of being orthogonal to $(1,0,2)$ and to $(3,-1,0)$ are  respectively given by setting for instance $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ equal to that vector and equating the resulting expression to$~0$; this respectively gives the equations 
$$ \begin{align}
 x-2z+2y-2y&=0,\\ 3x-2x+6y+z&=0,
\end{align}
$$
or after simplification
$$ \begin{align}
 x\phantom{{}+0y}-2z&=0,\\ x+6y+\phantom0z&=0.
\end{align}
$$
Then $V^\perp$ is spanned by for instance $(4,-1,2)$. It happens that this vector is also in $V$ (it is the sum of the two given vectors spanning $V$), which shows that you are not dealing with an inner product here (which should be positive definite). Indeed $q(4,-1,2)=0$. (Such a vector orthogonal to itself is called an isotropic vector for the bilinear form.)

If $E$ is the whole space, one does have $\dim(V)+\dim(V^\perp)=\dim(E)$ here. But even that is only valid in general provided that that bilinear form is *nondegenerate*, meaning that no nonzero vector is perpendicular to *all* vectors. Even though the given bilinear form is indefinite, it *is* nondegenerate. That can be checked by checking that the Gram matrixof $b$
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\2&0&-1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
has nonzero determinant. So $\dim(V)+\dim(V^\perp)=\dim(E)$ could have been expected here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. (1) Could you show me how you derived the expression for the bilinear form? (2) So we have $dim(V^\bot) = 1$. Is it in general true that $dim(V)+dim(V^\bot)$ is equal to the dimension of the vector space we started with? (3) Also, could you show me how to find the intersection of two vector spaces in general (also by taking this instance)?

Comment: If I may ask a somewhat unrelated question: when you write $$b(v,w)=\begin{pmatrix} x_v& y_v& z_v \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} x_w \\ y_w \\ z_w\\\end{pmatrix},$$ (where $A$ is the matrix associated with the bilinear form $b$) is it true that $x_v, y_v, z_v$ and $x_w, y_w, z_w$ should be the components of $v$ and $w$ with respect to the basis which we have considered when writing $A$?

Comment: The expression for $b$ is obtained by polarising $q$, as stated in the question. It is the unique symmetric bilinear form such that $b(v,v)=q(v)$ for all vectors $v$. Simply split $x^2$ into $x_1x_2$, and $2xy$ into $x_1y_2+y_1x_2$ etc. As for intersection of subspaces, that is basic linear algebra. A fairly easy method is to use an _equation_ for one subspace, and look for linear combinations of the _generators_ (basis vectors) of the other subspace that satisfy the equation. In fact you are in that situation here: $V^\perp$ is given by an equation, and for $V$ you have a basis.

Answer (score 1):

you want to find $(x, y, z)$ so that it is orthogonal to $(1,0, 2)$ and $(3, -1, 0)$
that means $x + 2z = 0, 3x - y = 0$ if the basis of is more complex you will make a matrix made of these vectors as rows and row reduce them to solve for $x,y,z.$ in this example it is easier and we can set $z = -1$ and solve for $x = 2, y = 6$ so that $V^\perp$ is spanned  by $(2, 6, -1).$

the dimension of $W$ and $W^\perp$ should add up to the dimension of the space these are subspaces of.

---

edit: $\pmatrix{1&0&2&|&a\\3&-1&0&|&b} \rightarrow 
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 2&|&a\\0&-1&-6&|&-3a + b}$

here $z$ is free variable and set it to $z = -1$. back substitution gives you $y = 6, x = 2$

if you had more than one free variable, you will set one of them to $1$ and the all rest to zero, then cycle through all of the free variables to get that many solutions in $W^\perp$

Comment: Many apologies, I had forgotten to write the quadratic form assigned. Could you update your answer, please.